# How does Magane's power work?

Tags: re-creators

I'm watching Re:Creators but even after 9 episodes of the anime, I still don't understand how Magane's powers work. So, the question is, how does it work?

[Wikipedia states this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Re:Creators#Creations) but I still don't understand it.

> She possesses an ability called "Infinite Deception of Words" that allows her to bend reality through lies and deception; by telling a lie and manipulating somebody into rejecting that claim it creates a "lie of a lie" which by proxy makes the initial claim become real.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a bit of a logic puzzle which kind of pays homage to the smart-villain trope. (Death note, Code Geass, Future Diary, etc).

To put things simply think of the analogy "two wrongs don't make a right".

In short, if you do something wrong, doing something wrong in return doesn't make it ok.

Well, her power takes a similar approach but to an extreme measure. If she can generate a lie and get a person to reject an obvious lie, then it generates truth. How? Because False + False = True. How? Because that's just how her power works - it's a play on boolean logic.

It's impressive but can be equally powerless, because if you don't reply to her statements it has no power. It requires a person to hear what she says and believe the opposite.

For example if she says "It will rain and you will die in a tornado" And I say "No way". What happens?

Comment: I die in a tornado?
Thanks for the answer. I understand it now. Is my answer correct though?

Comment: Exactly, but it does not start raining, because it is the second lie(the lie inside the lie) that comes true :D

Answer (score 7):

[@kaz's answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/40731/) sounds pretty much right to me; I just want to explicitly illustrate how her ability has worked in the cases we've seen so far.

## Episode 6, first time

Magane writes in the book that the shopkeeper will be attacked by Hounds of Tindalos. This is a lie: Magane does not have the intrinsic ability to summon Cthulhuian monstrosities. Magane asks the shopkeeper whether he thinks that it's a lie; the shopkeeper replies that it obviously is a lie. Since the shopkeeper disbelieved her lie, her lie becomes truth, and so Hounds of Tindalos magically appear to devour the shopkeeper.

## Episode 6, second time

Magane tells Aliceteria that her lance will end up piercing herself instead of Magane. This is a lie: Magane presumably does not have the ability to redirect weaponry. Aliceteria describes this statement as "nonsense". Since Aliceteria disbelieved her lie, her lie becomes truth. Had Selesia's arrival not prevented Aliceteria from making contact, she likely would've been magically run through by her own lance, given that Magane said her "a lie about a lie"line.

(It's unclear to me whether Magane actually needs to utter the "a lie about a lie" line for her ability to trigger or not. It might be just for show.)

## Episode 9

Magane tells Mirokuji that his attacks are "nothing" to her. This is a lie: if Mirokuji were to land a hit on her, she would likely be in bad shape. Mirokuji calls her on her bluff ("I've never met anyone who was fine after getting hit with this"). Since Mirokuji disbelieved her lie, her lie becomes truth, and so Magane is now magically immune to Mirokuji's attacks, or at least his attacks with "this" (i.e. his sword).

Comment: Can you edit to explain how her ability allowed Setsuna to appear in episode 20?

Answer (score 0):

In comparison to another work, Rick and Morty would tackle her power indirectly in the episode Amortycan Grickffiti. The demons enjoy pain which causes them pleasure. "Today is a bad day, which is GOOD, which causes me pain, WHICH is the BEST day!" Rick created a gun that inverts that back to its original statement, "Today is NOT the best day, because it causes me pain, which is bad, which is why it's a bad day." He created a gun to do this called an "Aversion-Converting Inversion Reverter" gun.

So to defeat her, you'd have to believe her lie.

"It will now rain and dogs will kill you." There are TWO lies there, so denying ANY of these lies would make the statement TRUE (A Lie of a Lie turns itself inside out)

So if you'd say "No way," it would make it true and dogs will kill you.